# SQL Server geometry datatype in .NET 4 and entity framework code first

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ef-code-first, geometry

I am using Entity Framework Code First 4.4 and .NET 4.0 in my application. 
I am working with database that already designed. 
this project is about geography systems. there is one field with type 'geometry' in database . database is SQL Server 2008 R2 . I can't upgrade to .NET 4.5 because we have many customers that they use windows XP as OS.

Since I use .NET 4.0 I can't use System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry in my POCO classes.
Is there any way or trick exist that map SQL Server 'geometry' datatype into C# string variable or any other datatype ?

Comment: May be helpful: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/yes-you-can-read-and-probably-write-spatial-data-with-entity-framework/ but its not about Code first, its about EF 4 interacting with geometry data type